# How to split a SAS datset with a set Number of Lines into a sas dataset/or a TXT file?

Tags: sas, radix

I have a claim data set which i want to split into TXT files. The main issue is that a single TXT file can contain just two claims(should write all occurances of a claim) and the Next claim  should be written into another txt or a dataset i.e. if i have 10 claims in a file i should be having 5 files/dataset as output.

My data Looks like this:

```
                                         Obs    Tin          Claim_Id
                                         1    271408630    EDY03JHKK00
                                         2    271408630    EDY03JHKK01
                                         3    271408630    EDY03JHKK01
                                         4    271408630    EDY03JHKK01
                                         5    271408630    EDY03JHKK01
                                         6    271408630    EDY03JHKK01
                                         7    271408630    EDY03JHKK01
                                         8    271408630    EDY03JHKK01
                                         9    271408630    EDY03JHKK01
                                        10    271408630    EDY03JHKK01
                                        11    271408630    EDY03JHKK01
                                        12    271408630    EDY03JHKK01
                                        13    271408630    EDY03JHKK01
                                        14    271408630    EK359VRPM00
                                        15    271408630    EK359VRPM00
                                        16    271408630    EK359VRPM00
                                        17    271408630    EK359VRPM00
                                        18    271408630    EK359VRPM00
                                        19    271408630    EK359VRPM00
                                        20    271408630    EK359VRPM00
                                        21    271408630    EK359VRPM00
                                        22    271408630    EK359VRPM00
                                        23    271408630    EK359VRPM00
                                        24    271408630    EK359VRPM00
                                        25    271408630    EK359VRPM00
                                        26    271408630    EK359VRPM00
                                        27    271408630    EK359VRPM01
                                        28    271408630    EK359VRPM01
                                        29    271408630    EK359VRPM01
                                        30    271408630    EK359VRPM01
                                        31    271408630    EK359VRPM01
                                        32    271408630    EK359VRPM01
```

Trying it in base sas

Comment: What are the output filenames ?

Comment: Can have Output filename such as out1 for first 3 claims out2 for next 3.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `FILE` statement `FILEVAR=` option to change the output file during the running data step.

Presume the data set is presorted by `Claim_Id`, or that within `Tin` the `Claim_Id`s are sorted.  `BY` processing can count the number of groups encountered and change the filename every 2 groups.  Adjust the modulus test and divisor in the file name construct if the number of claims in each text file is 3 (or some other #) instead of 2.

```
data have;
  do tin = 1 to 20;
    do claimid = 1 to 9;
      do item = 1 to ceil(20 * ranuni(123));
        value = 100 + floor(50*ranuni(123));
        output;
      end;
    end;
  end;
run;

data _null_;
  set have;
  by tin claimid;

  if first.claimid then do;
    retain claimgroup 1;
    claimgroup+1;
    if mod(claimgroup,2) = 0 then filename = cats('c:\temp\claims_pair#', claimgroup/2);
  end;

  file pairs filevar=filename dlm=','; 

  put tin claimid item value;
run;
```